# auto-adjusting "span" classes with twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I must code an html viewer which take some objects as input and provides a nice html layout. For the layout part I decided to use **twitter bootstrap 2.3**

**prerequisites**

- The objects are represented as **divs** of different size
- I don't know the **number** of divs to display in advance

Now, what I want is an "auto-adjusting" layout able to displace in the most convenient way the object in the screen. The concept is sketched in the following image:

[image]

on the **left** you can see the **objects**, on the **right** the **desired final diplacement**.
I nearly get it work in this way:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="node span6">a box</div>
    <div class="node span6">a second box</div>
    <div class="node span6">a third box</div>
    <!--as much divs as you want-->
</div>
```

but in the second line I get a bad "tilted-right" effect due to the `margin-left` settings of the bootstrap css.

[image]

I also tried to override the css specification of the `span` to adopt a margin-right driven approach but with no luck (if it is interesting I can provide info about this approach).
Any suggestions?

Comment: You are not using bootstrap correctly. The grid is made up of 12 elements so if you use `span6` for a div you can only use one more or two `span3`s.

Comment: True that. If memory serves, what you've described is what you'll see if you use Bootstrap as it was intended.

Comment: well, You're right. But according to bootstrap guidelines, I need to include in a `row` class a number of `spanX` classes that sum up to 12. This imply I know how to arrange the content in advance (i.e. I know where a `row`starts and ends). This is **not my case**. I'd like to add a bunch of divs in some sort of container and let them adjust automatically.

Comment: Bootstrap is intended for static layouts or layouts in which you know the amount of content before rendering it. It doesn't really suit your needs. I suggest checking out Masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com/) or another JS library like it to handle a dynamic layout like you want.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I'll check the Masonry capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using bootstrap and the `:nth-child` pseudo selector. However, this that you are trying to accomplish will also require that you make CSS changes beyond the simply `.span`'s left margin... You will probably need to re adjust this with smaller `@media` queries and it's probably outside the scope of this question to show you how to do all that, however... this should get you going:

### [Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/6G32Y/)

The fiddle above has bootstrap loaded... I'm making a container with the class `.row-fluid` in which I'm adding many `.span6`'s, but I am also making sure that on the third and then every two more `.span6` it's removing the left margin so it stacks two and two `.span6` per row.

You can read more about the `:nth-child` [pseudo selector here](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)

Comment: your solution is effective (and also elegant) when I have `divs` of omogeneous size, but when the size is different it doesn't solve the problem. I reproduced the issue in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LdPDr/1/), you can check yourself.

Comment: Hi @maVVamaldo this is simply because the floats are not being cleared The div with content is pretty long and the div next to it is fine (#4) but then #5 starts right below the #4 but without the margin on the left. So that's how you get what you see in your fiddle. The only way I can think of is to wrap every two spans in a row. Here is a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/VutLp/ Understanding this should get you in a better position to make the right choice on what to do... Let me know if it solves your issue to add it to my main answer.

Comment: hi @sulfureous, thank you for your suggestions. Despite it is a better arrangement, it is not the expected result. It would be great to have what you see in the first figure (first row) of my question. In other words, in [your example](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/VutLp/) the divs 5 and 6 should position beneath the div 4 and on the right side of the large div. I manage to get some results by setting the `margin-left: 0px;` property for all the spans and removing the border for a nicer look, but I don't consider it a solution, just a workaround.

Comment: You will need jQuery or JS as @ssorallen suggested. If JavaScript is an option then you can checkout the Masonry plugin by "Desandro". http://masonry.desandro.com/ - Here is another question dealing with an issue that you will face while doing this with a fluid grid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446061/jquery-masonry-with-percentage-width